# -initWithDocumentTypes iCloud crashes only in production build

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements, icloud-documents

I am using iCloud capabilities to choose files from iCloud by using UIDocumentMenuViewController. It is working fine in development build but whenever I upload build with production provisioning profile on Testflight my app produce a crash in line `[[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"]                                                    inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];`

I make archive in one machine and then create production build by using command-line on different machine.

I also checked the provisioning profile for production, and found all the capabilities are included under entitlement section.

Can someone help ?

Comment: You checked the provisioning profile on the Apple developer site?  Did you also confirm that you only have the latest, correct version of the provisioning profile on the Mac where you are doing the command line build? I would delete all the old provisioning profiles, because if you have an older profile that is valid for the app ID, but doesn't have the latest entitlements, it can pick the wrong one when building.

Comment: Yes. Everything correct. The problem is I need to create archive with commandline. at that moment the entitlements for iCloud are not being included.  When I make archive by xcode it works fine.

Comment: Obviously something is no correct, or you wouldn't be getting the error.  Did you confirm that you don't have multiple provisioning profiles on production build machine for the app's bundle ID?  An old version could be causing your problem.

Comment: I found the solution the archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent file was missing

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** As I was creating archive with command-line without code-signing (provisioning profile) system was ignoring the entitlements ad not creating the entitlements file (entitlement file `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` was not being created inside archive package or APP_NAME.xcarchive).

**Solution**: I wanted `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` file, so I created archive with Xcode by including provisioning profile and the package had the `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` file inside it. I copy this file everytime when I create archive by command-line without code signing. I copy this `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` file inside the archive package.

PS: If we change app capabilities we need to create new `archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent` as entitlements would changed.

Thanks everyone for your suggestion and comments :-)